# JavaScript CANVAS drawing LineTo function error

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image: Output as on the browser (cropped)]

Question 1: The path that it is drawing is not correct. It draws with the wrong dimensions (Infinite length rectangle). The code seems fine.

Question 2: How do we incorporate the color in text form to fill the rectangle?

**HTML part of the code:**

```
Color of OBJECT = <input type="text" name="clr" value="red"/><br/><br/>

Start Co-ordinates (x, y)= <input type="text" name="xco1" value="20"/> , <input type="text" name = "yco1" value = "20"/><br/><br/>

Dimensions (l x b) = <input type="text" name="length1" value="100"/> x <input type="text" name = "breadth1" value = "50"/><br/><br/>

<button onclick="drawRect()"><h3>Draw Rectangle</h3></button>

<button onclick="clearCanvas()"><h3">Clear Canvas</h3></button><br/><br/>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:4px solid #000000;">

</canvas>
```

**JavaScript part of the code:**

```
function drawRect()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var colr = document.getElementsByName("clr")[0].value;

    var xcrd = document.getElementsByName("xco1")[0].value;
    var ycrd = document.getElementsByName("yco1")[0].value;
    var len = document.getElementsByName("length1")[0].value;
    var brd = document.getElementsByName("breadth1")[0].value;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(xcrd,ycrd);
    ctx.lineTo(xcrd+len,ycrd);
    ctx.lineTo(xcrd+len,ycrd+brd);
    ctx.lineTo(xcrd,ycrd+brd);

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: BTW... To incorporate color, I tried using ctx.fillStyle = colr + "" ; and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because it's treating all the values taken from the inputs as strings.  You need to convert them to numbers, eg by using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var xcrd = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("xco1")[0].value, 10);
var ycrd = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("yco1")[0].value, 10);
var len = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("length1")[0].value, 10);
var brd = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("breadth1")[0].value, 10);
```

When they're being used as arguments by themselves to a function, they're automatically coerced into numbers.  However, when you do:

```
ctx.lineTo(xcrd+len,ycrd+brd);
```

They're still being treated as strings during the addition, so it's doing concatenation instead, so the function is being called as:

```
ctx.lineTo("20"+"100","20"+"50");
```

which ends up as

```
ctx.lineTo("20100","2050");
```

which is why you're seeing such a big rectangle. [Here's a complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1dpg37f/) with the number parsing in.

Also, just for completeness, it's worth mentioning that there are [built in functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Drawing_rectangles) for drawing rectangles, just in case you're not aware.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot. I did a calculations with javascript before but it didn't seem to do it this way.

Comment: I was trying to do all the shapes just using primitives and not the pre-defined functions.

Comment: Just as a tip: you can also convert numeric string numbers by prepending a plus in front of them, eg. `+"20" + +"100" = 120`, or `var xcrd = +document.getElementsByName("xco1")[0].value;` (just remember to add a space in front..)

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg quite right - I always forget that option!